# htaccess redirect ip/~folder to /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/folder folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am a newbie in the .htaccess language and I would like to achieve the following thing: When an user types an http://ZPANEL-IP/~Website it will show him the contents of the /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/Website folder. I tried doing that using RewriteCond, but didn't manage to do it, how can I achieve it, and if I do the code, where should I put it? Into Apache's default htacces or into the zpanel's htaccess configuration file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a htaccess file, write 
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule \~Website /website [L,QSA]
And place the file under public html

Comment: I forgot to add, where ~Website is one random website. It can be anything.

Comment: If anything then use ^(.+)$ instead of \!Website. Thus what ever the url is, it will be redirected to the directory "website".